# Using .Any from System.Linq on array to find a string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq

I'm trying to find out whether a particular cell in my array contains part of a given string. Since arrays don't use .Contains I'm using .Any, but it seems my understanding of how .Any works is too hazy to get it right.

```
public void ProcessCSV (string typeName) {

    for (int y = 0; y < CSVReader.grid.GetUpperBound(1); y++) {
        if (CSVReader.grid[0,y] != null) {
            if ((CSVReader.grid[0,y].Any(s => typeName.Contains(s)))) {
                  // (add it to a new list)
```

So I'm feeding in strings like "Pork", "Farm" etc. Sometimes it seems to work perfectly, e.g. if typeName is "Farm" I only get back rows from the array that include that string in [0, y]. But at other times, if I'm using Farm, another string or random gibberish, it just returns every single row that has any string at all.

What's actually happening when I call .Any in this way? Is there some alternate method I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have it the wrong way around.

`Any` will return a boolean indicating whether *any* element in the sequence meets the condition. When you type `Any(s => ...)`, `s` is the element from the sequence that gets checked.

So when you type:

```
.Any(s => typeName.Contains(s))
```

...you are essentially asking:

> Is *any* element from the sequence contained in the string `typeName`?

For example, if `typeName` is `Pork`, `Any()` will only return `true` when `"Pork".Contains("ork")`. You probably meant it the other way around:

```
.Any(s => s.Contains(typeName))
```

> Does *any* element contain the string `typeName`?

So that `"Pork and beef".Contains("Pork")` returns `true`.

---

If you want the *first* element (instead of a boolean truth) from the sequence that that meets the condition, use `FirstOrDefault` (or, when you know there is always at least one, you can use `First` instead). For example:

```
.FirstOrDefault(s => typeName.Contains(s))
```

> Return *the first* element from the sequence that is contained in the string `typeName`; or the default value when there is none.

Or, the other way around (which I still think you meant):

```
.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains(typeName))
```

> Return *the first* element from the sequence that contains the string `typeName`; or the default value when there is none.

Comment: Er, yeah! That should have been obvious ;) But switching it around that way gives me an error again, about .Contains -- maybe because I can't use .Contains with an array, and s is part of the array? Is there any good way around this?

Comment: One of the two errors I'm getting is this: "Type `char' does not contain a member `Contains' and the best extension method overload `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<string>(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: @ChrisMorrison Then you should read your errors more carefully. It says that you are trying to call `Contains` on a `char` (a single character). You are apparently expecting `CSVReader.grid[0,y]` to return a string, but this is not (always?) the case. Use the [`String` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9.aspx) to turn your single `char` or character array into a string.